# Parsing nested JSON array in android

Tags: json

I am trying to parse this json in android and displaying the contents in list.
I am able to retrieve title,location and creator but dont know how to get inside des_update and retrieve text on '0'

```
[
    {
        "title": "my event ",
        "location": "Chennai, Tamil Nadu, India",
        "creator": "abc",
        "des_update": {
            "0": "this is my event with moderator"
        }
    },
    {
        "title": "my event 17",
        "location": "pune",
        "creator": "abc",
        "des_update": {}
    }
]
```

this is my parsing code I want to display data in alist

```
 // convert json string to json array
JSONArray aJson = new JSONArray(sJson);

// create apps list
List<events> apps = new ArrayList<events>();

for(int i=0; i<aJson.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject json = aJson.getJSONObject(i);
    events app = new events();
    app.setTitle(json.getString("title"));
    app.setDate(json.getString("date"));
    app.setLocation(json.getString("location"));

    // add the app to apps list
    apps.add(app);
    ...
 }
```

Comment: post your parsing code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the following code:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);

JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);

JSONObject desObject = object.getJSONObject("des_update");

String data = desObject.getString("0");

System.out.println(data);
```

Here first you are loading your json string into JSONArray, and then you are taking one object from JSONArray instance. As **des_update** is an object with in the object you need to get that object calling getJSONObject() by passing your key and from there you can load the data that you want to use.

Comment: thanks for solving my problem...solution worked..:-)

Answer (score 0):

```
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonString);
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++)
        {
            JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String title = object.getString("title");
            String location = object.getString("location");
            String creator = object.getString("creator");

            JSONObject des_update = object.getJSONObject("des_update");
            String str = des_update.getString("0");
            System.out.println("des_update-------" + str);
        }
```